# Windows 8.1 Task Bar Context Menu Error

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I'm sorry if this is the wrong place but I really don't know where to go for something like this.

I did a fresh install of Windows 8.1 on my new SSD and the context menus for the task bar looks like this now...

[image]

I realize this may not be the right place to post, but could you point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow is for *programming* questions. [Super User](http://superuser.com/) is a better place for this question.

Comment: Thank you. I thought Super User was for Linux administration though. I'll have to relook at that.

Comment: Super User is "for computer enthusiasts and power users." I think there is a whole site dedicated to Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to uninstall Windows Update KB3072318.

https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/3f4yz9/my_jump_list_icons_are_huge_and_weird/

Comment: I talked to Microsoft and they know about this issue and will fix it with a new update .

Answer (score 0):

You get this graphical glitch because you use a custom Windows 8 theme under Windows 8.1. Microsoft changed the format a bit. [StartIsBack+](http://startisback.com/) (for Windows 8.1) fixes this issue and restore the Win7 Start menu for a better Windows 8.1 UX.

Comment: I just did a fresh install of Windows 8.1 though, how could that happen? I prefer to not download 3rd party software just fix a bug.

Comment: So I gave in and installed it, but it still didn't fix the issue.

Comment: do you use a 3rd party theme or the default Windows theme?

Comment: Default. I didn't change any theme settings after a fresh install.

Comment: I have no idea why you see this. I only know that old Win8 themes cause it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, forget my previous answer! It's got nothing to do with the SSD.
I just found a fix/workaround:
Just make a clean install with the internet completely disconnected and only connect after the setup is fully finished.
Also, this way, you won't even see the windows 10 upgrade notification on the setup.

Hope this helps...